# Validation password not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on sign up form using html form , but i am facing problem my password cannot validate when I enter wrong password and enter write past does not show anything so what should i do any help.

```
function validate(){
var = pass(document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var = pas1(document.getElementById("cpwd").value;
if (pass==pas1)
{
}
else
{
alert("Try again");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="style2 style8">SIGN UP FORM!!!!</p>
<form onclick="validate()" action="insert.php" method="post">
  <table width="270" height="386" border="1" align="right" bordercolor="#993366" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><td width="260"><table width="232" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="style2">loginform</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="72"><span class="style5">Name</span></td>
      <td width="144"><label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" onblur="MM_validateForm('name','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" placeholder="Name" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="72"><span class="style5">Gender</span></td>
      <td><p>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="gender"/>
          <span class="style5">Male</span></label>
        <span class="style5" onfocus="MM_validateForm('fname','','R');return document.MM_returnValue"><br />
        <label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender" /> 
female</label>
        </span><br />
      </p></td>
    </tr>
  <td width="72"><span class="style5">DOB</span></td>
      <td width="144"><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <label>
      <input name="dob" type="text" id="dob" onblur="MM_validateForm('dob','','R');MM_validateForm('dob','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"/>
      </label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="style5">Password</span></td>
    <td><label>
      <input name="pwd" type="password" id="pwd" onchange="MM_validateForm('pwd','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" placeholder="password"/>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="72"><span class="style5">Confirm Password</span></td>
    <td width="144"><label>
      <input name="cpwd" type="password" id="cpwd" onchange="MM_validateForm('cpwd','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
      </label>    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label>
      <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Signup" />
        </div>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
    <label></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "date", {format:"yyyy/mm/dd"});
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting it inside jsFiddle next time

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters,

```
var = pass(document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var = pas1(document.getElementById("cpwd").value;
```

should be

```
var pass = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var pas1 = document.getElementById("cpwd").value;
```

Edit:

Also, change `onclick="validate()"` to `onclick="return validate();"` and add `return false;` after the `alert("Try again");`.

Comment: @Adil: Edited my post again. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Just small change in your code

```
function validate(){
  var pass = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
  var pas1 = document.getElementById("cpwd").value;
  if (pass==pas1){
  }
  else{
    alert("Try again");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no `pass` in your content. You are writing it as:

```
var = pass(document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var = pas1(document.getElementById("cpwd").value;
```

Which should be this:

```
var pass = (document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var pas1 = (document.getElementById("cpwd").value;
```

Because the variable's name comes before the `=` sign. To show that this variable is having this value!

So, now lets use this one and try it like this:

```
if(pass==pas1) {
  // save the password or whatever
} else {
  // please try again..
}
```

This way, the user will check the inputs again. And it they are not working. Then you must first check that whether you are using correct ID of the element, or you are using ClassName as ID!

That's what the issue might be.

Comment: Then brother, the issue is not the vars I think, its with the ID or something like that!